# Bean is populated on instantiation but its fields are null upon destroy

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, configuration, dependency-injection

I have a class like this:

```
    public class Loader implements DisposableBean { 

        Class1 c1;
        Class2 c2;

        Loader(Class c1, Class c2) {
          this.c1 = c1;
          this.c2 = c2; 
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        c1.do();
        c2.do();
    }
}
```

It is created as a @Bean in a @Configuration class.

```
@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME, name = "loader")
public Loader getLoader() {
    return new Loader(getC1(), getC2());
}
```

And it gets instantiated via context loader listener in my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext-loader.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

With that app context having this line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="name.of.package.loader.is.in" />
```

I put a breakpoint in the constructor upon starting the war in tomcat and I can verify that both c1 and c2 are populated as expected. However, when I shutdown tomcat and it goes into the destroy method, both c1 and c2 are null and thus an NPE is thrown. Why would these values no longer exist?

---

Ah, darnit, should have dug down a bit further.  It was getting cleared in a section of the code I wasn't familiar with and I finally tracked it down.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the same instance of `Loader`?

Comment: @axtavt As far as I can tell. Any thoughts on how I could make sure?

Comment: Is the class mutable?  Can something be setting `c1` and `c2` to `null` at some point?

Comment: Log its hashcode in constructor and `destroy()` (`System.identityHashCode()`, if `hashCode()` is overriden).

Comment: @axtaxt I managed to figure it out. It was getting cleared in a section of the code I wasn't familiar with and I finally tracked it down.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Yes, that did end up being the problem. I wasn't aware it was doing so.